# Save list attachments in a document library

Tags: document-library, list-form, attachments

could anyone advise me if it is possible to change the default storage location of a list item attachment to a document library which is located in the same site? The idea is that information which is attached to a list item will be stored in a document library and that the meta-data of the attachments is automatically assigned based on the meta-data of the line item in the SharePoint list to which the document(s) is/are attached.

Thanks in advance for your support.

Answer (score 2):

List item attachments are not stored in Document Library. It is a part of the list item which is located with a correlation to the item in a Content DB. Document library is a separate independent entity.

You can add a lookup to the document library and define the list item id or title in the document library. Also when you add a lookup, you can include additional fields too. Which will give the functionality you expect here. Also it has many advantages such as versioning when compared with the list item attachments.

But if you have the documents attached, it saves the queries when you are using the object models.

I have used both and I prefer the document library rather attachment for most cases. Attachments also used for simple operations.

Answer (score 0):

You could simply create a Power Automate Flow, to save form attachments to a document library.

This example flow saves file attachments into subfolders named by a field/column in the list.
[image]

Continued from above image, the "Apply to each" loop in more detail:
[image]